# Using custom vertex data in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bmesh, vertex-colors

Can float vertex layer data added with bmesh, be used in rendering?

Let us say we added some data to all verteces:

`bm.verts.layers.float.new('G')`

Can this "G" be used in Cycles rendering nodes? As a source for a factor, etc?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, only special custom data layers can be used in a render or the 3D view:

- [Loop UV](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLoopUV)
- Loop colour (i.e. vertex colour)
- [Vertex defom](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMDeformVert) (i.e. vertex groups) - but only indirectly, e.g. as deformation

If you want to see your data in a render, you need to transfer it to a UV layer or <del>vertex</del> loop colour layer first. To transfer to a colour layer, you can do something like this:

```
color_layer = mesh.loops.layers.color.new('Foo')
for vert in mesh.verts:
    val = vert[my_cdata]
    col = (val, val, val)
    for loop in vert.link_loops:
        loop[color_layer] = col
```

Then you can use the 'Foo' layer in a render.

Note that `val` will be automatically clipped to be between 0 and 1.

When transferring to vertex colours you will lose precision, because each channel is stored in a single byte (whereas float custom data is stored in 4 bytes). You can get better precision by using a UV layer, which stores floats - but only two channels (x and y). When using a UV layer, the values will not be color-managed; this can be useful or not, depending on your material. Storing in a UV layer is similar:

```
uv_layer = mesh.loops.layers.uv.new('Foo')
for vert in mesh.verts:
    val = vert[my_cdata]
    for loop in vert.link_loops:
        loop[uv_layer].uv.x = val
```

[image: Screenshot of node setup to use UV layer for colour]